# Why Bitmap.getConfig() returns null?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have some XML-Layout generated ImageView and i want to copy the image i click in a `LinearLayout` below.

I had assign the follow event to all the `ImageView`'s `onClick` events:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Take layout where i want to put my copy-image
    LinearLayout savingLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearSaved);

    //Create a new image
    ImageView savedImage = new ImageView(savingLayout.getContext());
    //Take the bitmap from the object i clicked
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)((ImageView)v).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    //Take the config of the bitmap. IT RETURNS NULL
    Bitmap.Config cfg= b.getConfig();
    //Copy the Bitmap and assign it to the new ImageView... IT CRASH (cfg == null)
    Bitmap b2 = b.copy(cfg, true);
    savedImage.setImageBitmap(b2);
    savingLayout.addView(savedImage);
}
```

So why `b.getConfig()` returns null? There is a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` instead of `b.getConfig()` as a workaround.

Comment: The `getConfig` isnt there because it's returns depends on what type of image and/or which device i have?